# Trouble with certain spell saving throws

Tags: pathfinder-1e, saving-throw

Some of them are a bit confusing.  Take, for example, [Ghoul Touch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/ghoul-touch).

It states "**Saving Throw** Fortitude negates," but in the text it mentions that it "causes all living creatures in a 10-foot-radius spread to become sickened (Fortitude negates)."

So is the fortitude saving throw able to negate only the stench that causes sickness or the paralysis as well for the original target of the spell?

There are a few others that are a bit confusing like this so I'd appreciate the clarification.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the main target of the ghoul touch spell get a saving throw?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/17094/does-the-main-target-of-the-ghoul-touch-spell-get-a-saving-throw)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **Saving Throw** line refers to how the spell functions for the **Target**. In the case of *ghoul touch*, the target may make a Fortitude save against the spell; if successful, the entire spell is negated. If not, the target is paralyzed and begins to release a sickening cloud.

The parenthetical has to do with the *cloud’s* saving throw, which is distinct from the *spell’s* saving throw. For example, imagine if *ghoul touch* did not involve a save at all, and a simple touch was sufficient. In this case, the **Saving Throw** text would be “None,” because the **Target** of the spell would not be offered a save. The cloud could still say (Fortitude negates), though, and then only those in the cloud (rather than the original target) would be offered a save, and only against the Sickening status of the cloud.

Comment: ok, makes sense, thanks for clearing this up